# Identify owner of public key certificate

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

Today I logged in and found these certs in my home directory (macOS):

```
3d001d000851363136363935_rsa_new.der
3d001d000851363136363935_rsa_new.pem
3d001d000851363136363935_rsa_new.pub.pem
backup_rsa_3d001d000851363136363935_rsa_new.der
backup_rsa_3d001d000851363136363935_rsa_new.pub.pem
```

The creation and modification dates are the same and are from 6 days ago. I'm very confused about how they got there and would like to understand more. Is there a way to identify which software moved them there or to discover the owner of the public certs? There is no meta info in the certs.

Comment: You could try grepping all the binaries on your box for the string “rsa_new”. You can also check your system logs for programs that were running at that time.

Comment: @JohnDeters Already checked logs—most have already been purged. Grep yields nothing useful. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case it's quite likely these keys were generated using the [CLI tool](https://github.com/particle-iot/particle-cli) for [Particle](https://www.particle.io/) (IoT software). That's because it creates key files with the same naming pattern as in your examples.

E.g.:

```
(hex device ID)_rsa_new.pub.pem
backup_(hex device ID)_rsa_new.der
```

([Relevant source code file](https://github.com/particle-iot/particle-cli/blob/5f2669228ecf493e786f31e09254d4868d428251/src/cmd/keys.js).)

So `3d001d000851363136363935` is the ID of a device you've been working with. If you don't recall using Particle explicitly, think of (Particle-powered) IoT devices you worked with in the past and follow [these instructions](https://community.particle.io/t/finding-your-device-id/26531) to find out their respective device ID to compare it with the one on the keys.

Here is sample output showing how `particle` creates keys with the same naming pattern:

```
% particle keys doctor 1a002d001547353236343033
running dfu-util -l
Found DFU device 2b04:d006
running dfu-util -l
Found DFU device 2b04:d006
running openssl genrsa -out 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.pem 1024
running openssl rsa -in 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.pem -pubout -out 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.pub.pem
running openssl rsa -in 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.pem -outform DER -out 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.der
New Key Created!
running dfu-util -l
Found DFU device 2b04:d006
running dfu-util -l
Found DFU device 2b04:d006
running dfu-util -d 2b04:d006 -a 1 -s 34:612 -U backup_rsa_1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.der
running openssl rsa -in backup_rsa_1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.der -inform DER -pubout -out backup_rsa_1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.pub.pem
Saved!
checking file 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.der
spawning dfu-util -d 2b04:d006 -a 1 -i 0 -s 34:leave -D 1a002d001547353236343033_rsa_new.der
dfu-util 0.8
...
```

[(Source)](https://community.particle.io/t/solved-photon-setup-failure-new-led-flashing-sequence/22277/20)